# How do I add an array of colored squares to JavaFX?

Tags: java, graphics, javafx, javafx-8

I need to display some information in JavaFX as a grid of colored squares. Here are some restrictions that I would prefer to be met:
- Click events. I think this means each would have to be a node? Unless a node can get the coordinates of the click.
- The squares to be ajacent, with no gaps.
- Outlining a particular square.
- If the array of squares is over a certain size, allow for scrolling.
- Resizing of all the squares.

Any help on these would be greatly appreciated. I've been using Swing for the past few years, and I have to un-learn a whole bunch of stuff and I'm still figuring out how to draw custom components and such.

Comment: I've mostly tried using SwingNode, but it's not working. I'd rather just discard Swing altogether. With JavaFX, I've tried making a skin class, extending Region, and using Canvas. I never got very far, because I'm not very familiar with the architecture of JavaFX so I'm not really sure where to even start.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a GridPane. But in order to color the different "cells" you will have to add nodes to it (afaik).

The Mouse event on a gridpane gives you quite a lot of information (basically all you wanted):

```
MouseEvent [source = Grid hgap=0.0, vgap=0.0, alignment=TOP_LEFT, target = Grid hgap=0.0, vgap=0.0, alignment=TOP_LEFT, eventType = MOUSE_CLICKED, consumed = false, x = 110.0, y = 52.0, z = 0.0, button = PRIMARY, pickResult = PickResult [node = Grid hgap=0.0, vgap=0.0, alignment=TOP_LEFT, point = Point3D [x = 110.0, y = 52.0, z = 0.0], distance = 724.0178566683622]
```

However your code would be easier to read if you just added event handlers to the different nodes in your "cells".

Im sure you could also adjust the TableView to your needs and might not need to fill cells with nodes for that (as with the grid view).

To have different nodes have different colours, just add your desired StyleClass to the node

```
object.getStyleClass().add("redCell");
```

and style it in css

```
.redCell {
    -fx-background-color: #123456;
}
```

**However usually I should have asked you what you have already tried first, since this isn't a platform to ask devs "how to do x" and get "this way". It's usually "I've tried this, but it doesn't work, what should I try next / what did I do wrong?" :)**

Comment: I figured there was a standard/common way of just drawing to the Scene. I just needed colored squares. Would I use a Node object, or a Region in the GridPane?

Comment: Well a Region is just derived from a Node and a Node should do the job, but in the end it should not really matter.

Comment: It varies depending on the information inputted into the program. Could be anywhere from 50-10000. And I know a Region is a Node, but since it would have added functionality, I'm not sure if that added functionality would interfere or help (like resizing?).

Comment: I don't know, never wrote a program with 10'000 squares in it ;)
However to get a good feel about how others work with squares, you can check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082063/chessboard-with-automatic-resizing).