# Resizing Chess Board JavaFX with numbers and letters

Tags: java, javafx, chess

I am trying to make a chess board using javaFX. I want to look like this picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQSp3.png)

Here is my code:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        final int size = 8 ;
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < size; col ++) {
                StackPane square = new StackPane();
                String color ;
                if ((row + col) % 2 == 0) {
                    color = "white";
                } else {
                    color = "black";
                }
                square.setStyle("-fx-background-color: "+color+";");
                root.add(square, col, row);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            root.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(5, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true));
            root.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(5, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Priority.ALWAYS, VPos.CENTER, true));
        }
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

In this program i define a constant(size) which determines the size of chessboard. Also it can be able to change from 2 to 16(size). As you can see, the letters on the bottom side are missing and the numbers on the right side. How can i add them? The code if from here:
[Chessboard with automatic resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082063/chessboard-with-automatic-resizing)

Comment: You wrote in your question: _the letters on the bottom side are missing_ Did you try adding an extra row to your `GridPane`?

Comment: Actually the code is on the main class and the scene builder does not show up the chessboard.

Comment: Maybe you should mention that the code in your question is copied from the accepted answer to this question: [Chessboard with automatic resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082063/chessboard-with-automatic-resizing)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68053251/resizing-chess-board-javafx-with-numbers-and-letters#comment120281802_68053251), but you can simply add another column and another row to the `GridPane`. Populate the first column with numbers. Populate the last row with letters.

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        final int size = 8;
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col <= size; col ++) {
                StackPane square = new StackPane();
                if (col == 0) {
                    Label label = new Label(String.valueOf(row + 1));
                    square.getChildren().add(label);
                }
                else {
                    String color;
                    if ((row + col) % 2 == 0) {
                        color = "white";
                    }
                    else {
                        color = "black";
                    }
                    square.setStyle("-fx-background-color: "+color+";");
                }
                root.add(square, col, row);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            StackPane square = new StackPane();
            char[] letter = new char[]{(char) ('A' + (i - 1))};
            Label label = new Label(new String(letter));
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, i, size);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            root.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(5, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true));
            root.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(5, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Priority.ALWAYS, VPos.CENTER, true));
        }
        int dim = (size + 1) * 50;
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, dim, dim));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is how it looks when I run it.

[image: chess board]

Comment: The code is working but if i change the size to 2 it will print a-h and i want to print from a to b if the size is 2. Similarly, if the size equals more than 8 the program does not show it properly. I want the chessboard to resizing.

Comment: @Danakas Surely you can modify the code to do that. You cannot expect to use this site to copy code completely as-is and expect other people to make every tiny modification you need.

Comment: That's a lot of repetitive code. Do `String[] columnLabels = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP".split("");`, and then you can create the column labels in a loop (and make it depend on `size`, assuming that's no bigger than 16).

Comment: @Danakas I modified the code in the answer. Now it works for any size chess board. Of course you will run out of letters if the size is greater than 26.

Answer (score -1):

Update!
I tried this code from the follow answer:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        final int size = 10 ;
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col <= size; col ++) {
                StackPane square = new StackPane();
                if (col == 0) {
                    Label label = new Label(String.valueOf(row + 1));
                    square.getChildren().add(label);
                }
                else {
                    String color;
                    if ((row + col) % 2 == 0) {
                        color = "white";
                    }
                    else {
                        color = "black";
                    }
                    square.setStyle("-fx-background-color: "+color+";");
                }
                root.add(square, col, row);
            }
        }
        StackPane square = new StackPane();
            if(size==2) {
                Label label = new Label("A");
                square.getChildren().add(label);
                root.add(square, 1, 2);
                square = new StackPane();
                label = new Label("B");
                square.getChildren().add(label);
                root.add(square, 2, 2);
            }
        if(size==4) {
            Label label = new Label("A");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 1, 4);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("B");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 2, 4);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("C");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 3, 4);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("D");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 4, 4);
        }

        if(size==6){
            Label label = new Label("A");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 1, 6);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("B");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 2, 6);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("C");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 3, 6);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("D");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 4, 6);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("E");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 5, 6);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("F");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 6, 6);
        }

        if(size==8){
            Label label = new Label("A");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 1, 8);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("B");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 2, 8);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("C");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 3, 8);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("D");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 4, 8);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("E");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 5, 8);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("F");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 6, 8);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("G");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 7, 8);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("H");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 8, 8);
        }

        if(size==10){
            Label label = new Label("A");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 1, 10);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("B");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 2, 10);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("C");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 3, 10);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("D");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 4, 10);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("E");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 5, 10);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("F");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 6, 10);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("G");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 7, 10);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("H");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 8, 10);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("I");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 9, 10);
            square = new StackPane();
            label = new Label("J");
            square.getChildren().add(label);
            root.add(square, 10, 10);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            root.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(5, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Priority.ALWAYS, VPos.CENTER, true));
            root.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(5, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true));

        }
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 450, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It is working, but is it a good way?